# Single-click to open an item in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way to configure Google Drive so that a single-click opens an item, as it used to be the case and as it can be configured in any decent file browser?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible. What you could do however is downloading [Google Drive Sync](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) which will sync the files to your local computer and configure the 1 click for opening files there.